# How to implement a myclassWith... method in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, autorelease

What's the best way to implement a method that returns an autoreleased object? Does the following code work correctly?

```
@implementation MyClass

-(void) myclassWithSomeParameter:(SomeType) parameter
{
    return [[MyClass allocWithSomeParameter:parameter] autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The return type must be `MyClass *`, you need to `alloc` the new instance, and it should be a class method rather than an instance method (otherwise you need an existing instance of `MyClass`).

```
+ (MyClass *)myClassWithSomeParameter:(SomeType)parameter {
  return [[[MyClass alloc] initWithSomeParameter:parameter] autorelease];
}
```

Then create instances like so:

```
MyClass *instance = [MyClass myClassWithSomeParameter:parameter];
```

Comment: Haha, sorry, I don't know why defined the function as void.